# How to get a header outside of its floated primary div and place it full width on the top of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a common HTML structure made of a 73% width div floated left containing a several elements, one of which is the header. And a 23% width floated right sidebar.

```
<div class="primary">
    <header>
    </header>
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
</div>
```

Is it possible to get the header (which is nested in the first div) go on the top of the page full width and display underneath that parent div to the left with the sidebar to its right?

All this, without having to change the HTML structure and get the header outside its parent div.

Basically, I have this:

[what I have](https://codepen.io/Franz333/pen/xaBmEq?editors=1100)

but I would like to get this:

[what I would like](https://codepen.io/Franz333/pen/yxwZXo?editors=1100)

without changing the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But the solution is a little hacky. If you had the ability to change the html, that would be best, but, if not, here you go:

Make the body, `position: relative;` and set your header to `position:absolute`. Now you can move the header anywhere relative to the body.

If you add margin-top to the body, then you will have some white-space where you can position your header. Set the header width to 100%, give your header a set height to match the amount of margin you gave the body, and boom.

There are other ways of doing it, but this is one.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  margin:0;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

div.primary {
  width:73%;
  float:left;
  background-color: yellow;
  color:black;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 2em;
}

div.sidebar{
  float:right;
  width: 23%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 2em;
}

header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100vw;
  top: -50px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="primary">
    PRIMARY
    <header>
        HEADER
    </header>
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
    SIDEBAR
</div>
```